# \resizebox - Error: \begin{aligned} allowed only in math mode

Tags: math-mode, errors, resize

This code snippet produces the error "\begin{aligned} allowed only in math mode. Missing $ inserted."

```
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
$$\begin{aligned}
\sin ^{2} \theta+\cos ^{2} \theta=1 & \quad
\sec ^{2} \theta-\tan ^{2} \theta=1 & \quad
\csc ^{2} \theta-\cot ^{2} \theta=1
\end{aligned}$$
%
}
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: The problem is using `$$` within a box. Displayed math expects that it is told how wide the space is it can fill, whereas the `\...box` commands expect that their contents has a fixed width. Moreover: Please post a small *complete* document that shows your problem, not just a snippet.

Comment: Ok thank you. Replacing `$$`with `$` solved it for me

Comment: What's the reason for `aligned` if there is just one line? Why not dividing the display into three line and remove the `\resizebox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *never* use `$$` in LaTeX. Well, there are rare situations in which `$$...$$` can be useful, but they're very special.

#### Why do you get the error?

When TeX is typesetting a *horizontal box*, which is part of the work of `\resizebox`, display math mode is not allowed and therefore `$$` just denotes an empty math formula. Hence, in your case, `aligned` is found outside of math mode, which is illegal and the error message tells you exactly this.

You should use `$...$` instead. Well, assuming you really want to do that.

#### Is `aligned` necessary?

Not at all: you need `aligned` to make multiline displays, but you have just one (very long) line. The only thing `aligned` does is to add additional space between the second and third formulas.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{center}
\resizebox{0.999\columnwidth}{!}{%
$\begin{aligned}
\sin ^{2} \theta+\cos ^{2} \theta=1 & \quad
\sec ^{2} \theta-\tan ^{2} \theta=1 & \quad
\csc ^{2} \theta-\cot ^{2} \theta=1
\end{aligned}$%
}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1][4-6]

\end{document}
```

Why `0.999\columnwidth`? Because the various roundings lead to a width of 229.50241pt, whereas the column width is just 229.5pt, so you get *two* lines. Here's the output:

[image]

Can you see the difference in the spaces? If you remove `\begin{aligned}` and `&`, you get

[image]

Why? Because `aligned` adds space after even numbered columns.

#### Why not doing a full display?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{gather*}
\sin ^{2} \theta+\cos ^{2} \theta=1 \\
\sec ^{2} \theta-\tan ^{2} \theta=1 \qquad
\csc ^{2} \theta-\cot ^{2} \theta=1
\end{gather*}
\lipsum[1][4-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]